# How to configure Fortify plugin using 'Jenkins Configuration As Code' Jenkins plugin (JCASC)?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, fortify, jcasc

I'm setting up a new Jenkins master server and configuring it using the Jenkins Configuration as code (JCASC) plugin.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/README.md

I've configured most plugins with JCASC, based on documentation and examples inside the project, but I can't find the syntax for configuring plugin 'Fortify Jenkins Plugin' version 18.10.

I need to set these properties:
URL of the remote Fortify server, authentication token (generated on the fortify server) and which template to use.

Can anyone assist with an example or syntax for the yml file used by the JCASC plugin for Fortify plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [fortify-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/fortify) is compatible with JCasC, it might be or it might need some modifications. That said, if it is compatible, then the configuration export should work for it.

So, spin up a Jenkins instance, install the plugin, configure whatever you want in the Jenkins UI and then go to the CasC page and use the configuration export. That should give you a JCasC file containing your setup.

Alternatively, you can try the JCasC Schema experimental feature. It's a JSON schema generated by Jenkins that you can use in your YAML editor for autocompletion. [More information here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/c7864838afa0c96b3469748000cf8684d1832883/docs/features/jsonSchema.md).

Answer (score 0):

we have just released an update of the [Fortify plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/fortify/#releases) with support for JCasC. Keep in mind, versions of the plugin prior to [v21.1.36](https://github.com/jenkinsci/fortify-plugin/releases/tag/v21.1.36) were unable to support it, we had to make changes to make it happen.

You can find official documentation on how to use our configuration elements [here](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-jenkins-plugin/2110/Jenkins_Plugin_Help_21.1.0/index.htm#InstallConfig/ConfAsCode.htm?TocPath=Installation%2520and%2520Configuration%257C_____4). There's one correction to the documentation, though. Our top level configuration element is called ***fortifyPlugin*** instead of *fortify* mentioned in the documentation. It is going to be corrected in the next documentation update.

Here's a sample configuration for your quick reference:

```
unclassified:
  fortifyPlugin:
    url: "https://qa-plg-ssc3.prgqa.hpecorp.net:8443/ssc"
    token: "3ab8c774-0850-483b-8be6-2907722a81d8"
    proxyConfig:
      proxyUrl: "web-proxy.us.softwaregrp.net:8080"
    projectTemplate: "Prioritized High Risk Issue Template"
    connectTimeout: "10"
    readTimeout: "20"
    writeTimeout: "10"
    breakdownPageSize: "50"
    ctrlToken: "5176d380-26ac-430f-95d7-0a2272cf3297"
```